# Using another service.yaml configuration file in unitest instead of default in symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I have a microservice that use JWT for authentication/authorization, and it just need a verify an jwt token is correct or incorrect, so in the code, i only implement the decoder for JWT.

```
    Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration:
        factory: [ 'App\Security\JWT\JWTConfigurationFactory', 'createJWTReader' ]
        arguments:
            - '%env(JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
```

this configuration will be injected to JWTManager. but as you see, i just implement the read part.

but in functional test, i need to generate some token to pass some functional test (call to authenticated endpoint.. eg) that need a encoder part.

my strategy is create a new file `service-test.yaml` and write a `createAsymmetricSigner` in factory to work both with read/write JWT.

```
    Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration:
        factory: [ '@CCT\Monolith\Shared\Symfony\Security\JWT\JWTConfigurationFactory', 'createAsymmetricSigner' ]
        arguments:
            - '%env(JWT_PRIVATE_KEY)%'
            - '%env(JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
            - '%env(JWT_PASSWORD)%'
```

and the problem is, how can i overide the symfony start up endpoint to make it take `service-test.yaml` instead of `service.yaml` for DI configuration file.

Comment: you can use `when@test` in your existing services file for that. See [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments)

Comment: @craigh is correct and this is the recommended way. You can also put your services in `config/services_test.yaml` as said in the doc